# Scrape Data without Repeating Data Already Saved

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a simple beautifulsoup script that scrapes data from a page periodically, and saves it as a json file. However, every time it runs, it goes over many of the same set of urls, and scrapes a lot of the same data, as well as any new data posted. How can I avoid duplication?

I have tried pickling the urls that have already been scraped but don't know how to build out the logic to stop the needless duplication in the scraping.

```
    for i in urlrange:
        urlbase = 'https://www.example.com/press-releases/Pages/default.aspx?page='
        targeturl = urlbase+str(i)
        req = requests.get(targeturl)
        r = req.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
        for row in soup.find_all('table', class_='t-press'):
            for link in row.find_all('a'):
                link = link.get('href')
                link = 'https://www.example.com' + link
                if link not in datalinks:
                    datalinks.append(link)
                    #print('New link found!')
                else:
                    continue

    pickling_on = open("links_saved.pkl","wb")
    pickle.dump(datalinks, pickling_on)
    pickling_on.close()

    for j in datalinks:
        req = requests.get(j)
        r = req.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
        for textdata in soup.find_all('div', class_='content-slim'):
            textdata = textdata.prettify()
            data.append({j:textdata})   

    json_name = "Press_Data_{}.json".format(time.strftime("%d-%m-%y"))

    with open(json_name,'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data,outfile)
```

I would like to scrape the data, without having to go over the urls that have already been processed by the script.

Comment: Have you tried storing the urls already scraped in a list, then simply check if the url scraped next time is in that list?

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the links in a set.

```
datalinks = [ ]
unique_links = set(datalinks)
```

This will remove all the duplicate links, so now only unique links will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
listwithdups = [ 'url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url2', 'url4', 'url4' ]    
uniqueList = [ i for i in listwithdups if i not in uniqueList ]
```

Breaking down the list comprehension:

```
listwithdups = [ 'url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url2', 'url4', 'url4' ]    
uniqueList = [] #declaring empty list

for i in listwithdups:
 if i not in uniqueList:
  uniqueList.append(i)
```